# I've made a bad vote

Tags: discussion, support

I'm really sorry, I've downvoted an answer before testing its contents, a mistake, I apologize.

This was an old vote, like a month before.

Now clearly the answer was nice, and I'd like to be able to vote it up, as I should have. Why can't I?

Please consider this topic, I feel this is a good discussion. What once was a bad answer can clearly become a good one over time. Things evolves.

Comment: 7 minutes(I think that's the maximum time to re-cast your vote, I might be wrong) have passed since you voted, you can only re-cast your vote if the post gets edited.

Comment: @JustDoIt I'm talking about old votes. I've edited my question. Nice input ty.

Comment: If you can improve the answer, you could edit it. They you could change your vote.

Comment: If new votes within 10 min cant be re-casted what makes you think an older vote can?

Comment: @JustDoIt answers qualities can evolve over time. Because things are constantly evolving.

Comment: You're asking why you can't re-cast your vote, simple, cause the vote is locked, no matter if you voted 10 min ago or a year ago... the answer remains, the post needs to be edited to re-cast your vote

Comment: @JustDoIt yes, these are the rules, I was (and still am) wondering why. But hopefully there are workarounds :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now clearly the answer was nice, and I'd like to be able to vote it up, as I should have. Why can't I?

Why is it *now* actually? Because you got a grip about the actual meaning of it over time?

Your only option is to edit the question, and retract your vote.

Not that I consider that's a really good option, and as you're above 2k you can hammer in a substantially useless edit like adding a newline (try to find something better to improve in the question/answer), but it's an option and reveals your shame at least.

Comment: Actually, I didn't post the question. I answered it, and had the accepted answer. But another answer was clearly better, and I believe it should appear as the "accepted" answer.

Comment: Yes, I voted down, thinking it couldn't work, but then, much later, I was proved wrong. And I feel kind of wrong by downvoting something right.

Comment: And **if you don't have over 2k rep**, then you can just return to the post in a few days and do it if the edit is accepted. Note that no edits remain unviewed for a week or longer.